# Why is rewriting in htaccess not working on this server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, htaccess, rewrite

I'm moving code from a server that served a single domain to one that serves multiple domains. I'm using named virtual hosts to handle the different domains. The url rewriting is not being executed

- I know that virtual hosts work on that server because the other domains work
- I know that this particular domain is working because when I hit pingtest.iguiders.com I see the index.html file I left in www/ping/. ('ping' is the dir that pingtest points to because, after my test works, the real domain, ping.iguiders.com will point here)
- I know that htaccess is generally working on this server because my other domains use it extensively.
- I initially copied pingtest.iguiders.com in /sites-available from another virtual host that uses htaccess and works. I just changed the server alias and the document root
- the virtual host definition does contain RewriteEngine On

Here is the entire .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 7

# Pings for ping server
RewriteRule ^0.02/ping/$ ping_functional.php [L,qsa]
RewriteRule ^0.03/ping/$ ping_functional.php [L,qsa]
RewriteRule ^0.04/ping/$ ping_functional.php [L,qsa]
RewriteRule ^0.05/ping/$ index.html [L,qsa]
```

But when I try pingtest.iguiders.com/0.05/ping/  I do not get the index.html file I expect (Nor do 0.02, 0.03, etc. work). I get a 404. I suspect that the .htaccess is not being accessed at all because I never see the rewrite log I defined.

Anything obvious I screwed up?

Comment: Is your apache caching the .htaccess? Is it possible to reload/start?

Comment: You have generated a rewrite log file .... what does it indicate?

Comment: @ott-- No such thing in Apache. One of the reasons for why enabling `.htaccess` (`AllowOverride`) is making it a lot slower. For each request it will recursively go through all directories for those files.

Comment: Actually, that's one of the hints that make me think the .htaccess file is not even being seen. There is no log file generated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you by any chance missing a `/` in your `RewriteRule ^0.02/ping/$`, between `^` and `0.02/ping/`?  What would happen if you remove `^` or replace it with a `^/`?

Comment: Well, I tried both of your suggestions but they had no effect. Removing the ^ shouldn't work because then rule would trigger only if the url started with those characters but the urls are pingtest.iguiders.com/0.02/ping/?parameters....